# Disable certificate verification on Weblogic

Tags: weblogic

The company where I'm working has very old legacy app that runs on Weblogic 10 server. App vendor is exist no more, but app itself is still used in some business processes. Month ago SSL certificate finally was expired. There's no way to re-issue it or somehow replace it, because the same certificate was used to sign license key.

Still, I want to try to restore access to management app (custom app, not the admin console). I need either to configure Weblogic to ignore expired certificate (best option) or disable SSL completely. The latter is more complicated because there're several apps on that server, plus, port 80 is redirected to 443.

I googled a lot, but all I've found is that Oracle only allow to ignore hostname verification. I've tried, but obviously it couldn't help. I've only worked with Tomcat, so could some please explain me how to disable certificate verification, if it's even possible.

This is how error looks like:

```
<Alert> <Security> <BEA-090154> <Identity certificate has expired
<Error> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000297> <Inconsistent security configuration, weblogic.management.configuration.ConfigurationException: Identity certificate has expired
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

I disabled SSL (in `confix.xml`) and configured some iptables redirects to work with HTTP. It seems that WLS can't ignore expired certificate, because vendors like Oracle "always know better" and other security hype.